# Cardview with vertical separator

Tags: android, android-cardview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13lWN.png)

Hello folks!

i'm stuck in how to create a cardview like the figure above (Link).
I try some ways but with no sucess, someone can help me out ?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code that you tried please

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` is just a fancy `FrameLayout`, and those "dividers" are just very thin `View`s. Here's just one of the many ways you could make something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="92dp"
            android:background="#f1f1f1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ccc"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#f1f1f1"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ccc"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#f1f1f1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: save my life! tks!